# Entry on an EU passport after deportation from the UK on an Israeli passport

Tags: uk, dual-nationality

Over 5 years ago I was deported from the UK after working illegally with my Israeli passport. I didnt get any stamp in my passport.

Today I have an EU passport and I'm coming for a visit on New Year's Eve.
I made an application to the UK agency for a tourist visa on my Israeli passport because I don't want any problems and they answer me to withdraw my application because I can travel to the UK with my European passport.

I've already have flying tickets.
Is it safe? Can it be that they will ask questions in the entry?

Comment: Did you make it clear in your application that you had been deported from the UK five years ago?

Comment: yes i send them all my documents that show that i was diported before 5 years

Comment: Terminology error: they do not deport for working illegally.  Instead you were 'removed'.  Big difference.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: @user38239 http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60240/11491

Comment: @GayotFow It might be likely that they were removed, not deported but you can not state that as a fact without the actual information.

Answer (score 8):

When you enter as EU citizen you use the UK and EU passport lanes at the airports and often you can even use a self service booth.
As you did not get a mark in your old passport, and the visa agency told you not to apply, I am sure you have no reason to be handled any other than any other EU visitor.

Answer (score 6):

Border guards are not supposed to ask any question to EU citizens and, as a matter of fact, I have never been asked anything when entering the UK. There are many reasons why your past problems are not really relevant now, one of them being that as an EU citizen, you are *entitled* to work in the UK so you cannot work illegally anymore.

Comment: so if i come with my fiancee i need to go with him or alone in the border? he doesnt have a eu passport.

Comment: @user38239 That's a completely different issue but feel free to ask a follow-up question about that. The exact nature of your relationship (For how long have you been together? Do you share a home? Do you have some sort of registered partnership?) might have a bearing on the answer.

Comment: What do you mean "Are not supposed to ask any question"? Aren't they supposed to verify who you are and make sure that your allowed to enter the country?

Comment: @andrewmh20 Yes but the point is that there isn't much to check beyond your ID and citizenship, certainly compared to almost any other border crossing situation I can think of. For example, the purpose of your trip, your history of travels to the UK, your finances, etc. are immaterial and border guards are not supposed to ask about that (whereas it is very common to query third country nationals entering the UK about that). In practice, border guards look at your ID, possibly run a database check and say “thank you” and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer is invalidated for the OP who may not have been deported at all but it still answers the question actually asked and may be the most helpful for others.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/who-needs-an-entry-clearance-ecb04/ecb04-who-needs-an-entry-clearance#ecb43-deportees

> ECB4.3 Deportees
>
> An applicant who has previously been deported from the UK at any time
>   must apply in writing for a revocation of the Deportation Order and
>   wait for the outcome of the revocation request before they can travel
>   to the UK (if a non-visa national) or before applying for an entry
>   clearance (if a visa national). An application for entry clearance
>   from a person with an extant Deportation Order will be refused
>   automatically. Entry in breach of a Deportation Order is a criminal
>   offence under section 24 (1) (a) of the 1971 Act. Any leave acquired
>   prior to the Deportation Order is invalid.
>
> **This also applies to any European Economic Area (EEA) national** - for
>   more guidance on these see EUN1.3.

So it seems that you won't be stopped at immigration as an EU citizen but you would be committing a criminal offence by not having the deportation order revoked first.

Comment: but i make an application and get an email aswer that say this: "we would like to informyou that we cannot process your visa application and kindly ask you to withdraw your visa application in as you hold an EU passport and can travel to the UK with your EU/POLISH passport"

Comment: They are saying you don't need a visa, they are not saying you don't need to get the deportation order lifted, you need to ask specifically about that.

Comment: i was removed for working illegal. i think its diffrent from deportation

Comment: The OP did use the word in the question but s/he almost certainly wasn't actually deported. That's for criminal offenders, which is why it also applies to EU citizens (whereas all the others reasons to refuse entry or remove foreign nationals do not apply to them).

Comment: so there is another law that deal my situation? how can i know if its enough to come after the answer ive got?

Comment: @JamesRyan, a well-intended answer, but the OP's situation is not a deportation case and the guidance you have cited does not pertain to the OP.

Comment: @GayotFow with respect, you are guessing that it is not a deportation case. My advice is to check and be certain.

Comment: @JamesRyan, did you see where the OP wrote: " I didn't get any stamp in my passport."?  That's important information as to what happened.