# Does voluntary departure from the UK count as deportation?

Tags: uk, deportation

If someone chose voluntary departure from UK, and is now filling a form to say have you ever been deported from another country, would they tick 'yes'

Then does a voluntary departure appear on travel records and is it considered a deportation.

Comment: In which circumstances did this voluntary departure happen? What happened _before it_? Which authorities were involved, and what did they tell the traveler?

Comment: Did you get any paperwork?  Even the form number can help.

Comment: From gov.uk "Remember that making a decision to remove an immigration offender (Form IS 151B), or issuing a notice identifying him as an immigration offender (IS 151A part 2) does not in itself mean that the applicant has been removed from the country. It is perfectly possible for someone to leave the country voluntarily after a decision has been taken to remove him."

Comment: The courts have also decided that ISIA Part1 (notice to a person liable to removal) isn't even a requirement to leave let alone a removal or deportation.

Comment: The UK does not consider it a deportation (I'm sure @GayotFow will be along shortly to give the full run down). But the creator of this form might still consider it a deportation.

Comment: @Calchas Wouldn't the answer depend on what the issuing country of the deportation/removal considers it?

Comment: @Calchas right, it would be a removal if it happened after 2001. But if the question were "have you ever been required to leave another country?" then having received an IS 151A (or B), the answer would be 'yes'.

Answer (score 9):

It is well established that a Voluntary Return is not the same as a Deportation and even not the same as a Removal. The answer provided by Gayot Fow 
 on [Difference between deportation and removal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal/60241#60241) provides a good distinction.

Further evidence of this distinction is they have different penalties.

[Immigration offender: RFL05, paragraph 320(7B) and A320](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-offender-rfl05-paragraph-3207b-and-a320/immigration-offender-rfl05-paragraph-3207b-and-a320#header2)

> **RFL5.2 How long are applicants automatically refused for?**
>
> 12 months if they left the UK *voluntarily, not at the expense*
>   (directly or indirectly) of the secretary of state;
>
> 2 years if they left the UK *voluntarily*, at the expense (directly or
>   indirectly) of the secretary of state, more than 2 years ago; and the
>   date the person left the UK was no more than 6 months after the date
>   on which the person was given notice of the removal decision, or no
>   more than 6 months after the date on which the person no longer had a
>   pending appeal; whichever is the later
>
> 5 years if they left UK *voluntarily*, at public expense;
>
> 5 years if they were *removed* from the UK as a condition of a caution
>   issued in accordance with s.134 legal aid, sentencing and punishment
>   of offenders act 2012
>
> 10 years if they were ***removed or deported*** from the UK;
>
> 10 years if they practised deception (which includes using false
>   documentation) in support of a previous visa application.

In your case however I would perhaps err on the side of disclosure and say YES and add an explanation. My reason for this is that the question seems a catch all covering all kinds of *deportation-like* events where for the sake of brevity all the different three scenarios were not enumerated. Of course the golden rule is not to volunteer information to immigration when you're not specifically asked.

However simultaneously I view UK consular officers very intolerant of any form of deception, misrepresentation or *appearance of deception* and they are not people to try to use technicalities on. Some more informed people may have a different opinion and I will gladly withdraw this answer if that is the case.

When I was [recently asked by immigration officer at Heathrow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-uk-previously-refused-should-i-apply-fo/89879#89879) *have you ever had any problems with immigration anywhere*, I chose to answer yes although the only problem I had ever had with immigration was a visa refusal. Someone could reasonably argue that being denied a visa previously does not count as problem with immigration however I chose not to risk saying no and being refused entry and banned for misrepresentation.