# Administratively removed 7 years ago, chances of returning to the UK?

Tags: visas, study, overstaying, removal, nigerian-citizens

I was administratively removed from the UK in 2010 after overstaying my student visa. I had completed my MSC programme in marine engineering.

I am Nigerian and now my state government is sponsoring me for a PhD programme in Strathclyde, Glasgow. I am married now (wasn't then) and this sponsorship covers all our living expenses for 3 years.

What are my chances of getting a visa? How can I be convincing enough that I will be returning back this time after my Phd since I have a job waiting for me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is primarily opinion based. Although you are free to apply to enter the uk (see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal) since you do not indicate you have a ban, nobody knows whether you will be granted the visa or not. or quantify your _chances_.

Comment: Slim and none and Slim is on his way out of town. Nigerian, overstay, administratively removed: Not a combination that will evoke much sympathy with ECO.

Comment: You will never know unless you apply.