# Can a person enter the EU if he is deported from the UK?

Tags: uk, eu-citizens, spouses, deportation, visa-bans

My husband is being deported from the UK in 2018. He is Lebanese, I am from the EU. Can he go to another EU country after he is deported from the UK, if his wife is from the EU?

Comment: What is the reason for his deportation?

Comment: The UK is part of the EU, still, Are you in the UK and are asking whether he can enter another EU country without you? Or, that you would both leave the UK for another EU destination?

Comment: Was he actually *deported*, or merely [removed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60240/39667)?

Comment: Are you in the UK now? Are you in the country he hopes to enter? Is it your country of citizenship?  EU freedom of movement is.likely to be involved here, but we don't have enough information to know whether it applies.

Comment: We both want to live in a another EU country than UK. Yes it will be my country of citizenship.