# With an overstay tag will l get another European Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, overstaying

I came into the UK in 2016 on a tier 4 Visa that was due to expire at the end of my course in September 2019. In December 2017 I was withdrawn from my course and reported to the Home office by my university  because I couldn't pay my tuition fees anymore. I got a letter from home office to leave the country within 2 months but now l have overstayed with more than 5 months. I want to apply to other European universities like in France, Poland and Bulgaria. With a tag of overstay that I have now will l be able to get another European Student Visa?

Comment: Nobody knows. You may or may not, likely **not**. Actions and lawlessness has consequences and rightly so. You are likely also working illegally.

Comment: Why didn’t you leave as directed? You are risking removal and its lifelong consequences for any future travel. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal/60241#60241

Answer (score 3):

For study, you will need a long-stay (D) visa rather than a short-stay (C) visa. Those are under national responsibility.

The [German form](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/207850/f9342033f2933dc05da54151efe283db/aufenthalten-data.pdf) asks if you have ever been expelled or deported **from Germany**, so you can honestly say no on that question. However, the form asks about your current place of residence and residence permit. Telling the truth means your chances go down, telling a lie means you can be deported if the truth ever comes out.

Comment: I will give my BRP card which states that my Visa expires in 2019 even though it was cancelled

Comment: @Tatenda, if you lie on the application and get found out, you will be banned from Schengen, too. Lying about something that is easily checked is stupid. What if you have to leave the UK before your new application is decided? You won't get back into the CTA anytime soon. Do you want to be kicked out of the rest of Europe, too?