# Will a UK visit refusal affect a previously granted USA visa?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals

Hello all and thanks for the help. 
My friend, despite having grown up in the uk, is not native and did not end up getting acquiring British citizenship.

He went for a visit to the uk a couple of months ago and was denied at the border for a visitor visa because he did not have his financial documents on him, and failed to explain that his education visa was terminated when asked (after moving back home). Clarification: he had attended university in the uk after primary, secondary school and college and dropped out and moved back to his home country. Upon arrival, he did not mention to the immigration agent that It had been terminated. I have read on here that those visitor visas cannot be appealed, though I believe it’s far too late anyway.

He is coming to visit me in America in a couple of months. He was granted a visitor visa and entry around three years ago with the visa expiring in a couple of years from now. Should we prepare for any potential issues because of the UK visa refusal? I would be gutted to not be able to see him. Sorry if this is a repeat question!

Comment: _and failed to explain that his education visa was terminated when asked (after moving back home)_ Not clear, explain clearly.

Comment: In any case it should not have a direct bearing on his visiting the USA. He should come normally with documents proving finances and ties to him country and answer all questions honestly at the airport when asked.

Comment: Hi honorary world citizen! I have tried to clarify on the post. Your advice gives me hope. Thanks :D

Comment: You can't get a visitor visa for the UK at the UK border, so things can't have happened as your friend described. That said, I shouldn't expect any problems except for on *future* visa applications.

Comment: @CMaster I think he was traveling on a visa which on the surface appeared valid but had actually been curtailed.

Comment: Ah yes, I see I may have misunderstood the description. Entry was refused for a visa holder because of some reason or other. Which makes this probably a *removal* rather than a *refusal*. Don't imagine that makes much difference in this case.

Comment: @Picca For clarity, what is his citizenship and which US visa does he have?

Comment: Hi everybody. He’s a Maldivian citizen. The letter was for “refusal of a visit visa.” I might have misunderstood how he obtained it- I thought it was at the border, but maybe not based on cmasters knowledge. I think his American visa is b2 but I know it’s valid for either 5 or ten years from issuance. Sorry that I don’t have my info together as much as I’d like you guys but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Picca You need to provide accurate information to get accurate answers. You need to ask him the accurate details so you don't send us after red herrings.

Comment: Sorry you guys. I didn’t mean to come off as a time waster. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

It should not have a direct bearing on his visiting the USA. He should come normally with documents proving finances and ties to him country and answer all questions **honestly** at the airport when asked.

Ultimately however for the USA visas only give you the right to appear at the border to be examined by an immigration officer. The officer makes the determination whether to allow you in or not.

Note that the USA and UK (together with some other countries) share some degree of immigrant application information. Their focus at this time [is on safety related issues and crime/terrorism](https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/733567/USA-and-Britain-agree-data-sharing-on-immigration-and-visas).

> Under the plan London and Washington will be able to access each
>   other's security databases to check that visa applicants do not have a
>   criminal record or pose a terror threat.

To be clear your friend was traveling on a visa which on the surface appeared valid but had actually been curtailed. Upon arrival, he was [removed at port](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal/60241#60241), not deported which is an important distinction.