# Applying for the UK Visa, previous "Ausreiseverplichtung(ordered to leave Germany),how to answer UK Visa question?

Tags: deportation

I have previously asked about my situation as a student Visa holder in Germany.I was a master degree student in Germany.Due to the pandemic and loss of my father,I was not able to register my master thesis on time.Due to this reason,the extension of my study Visa had been refused and I was given 9 days to leave Germany.I was issued Grenzübertritssbeschienigung(crossing the border certificate),which states that I have "Ausreiseverplichtung"(ordered to leave Germany-I am not sure if I can translate this German notion as "ordered to leave" but close to this meaning).I left voluntarily within the given time frame, so my return is also Freiwillige Ausreise(voluntary departure).
I am working on my master thesis from distant now and I am planning to apply for the PhD in UK.
On the UK Visa application form there are questions regarding "have your Visa, Residence Permit Application,Residence Permit Extension Application had been refused in UK or anywhere else?", "Have you been deported, removed,ordered to leave,have any entry ban from UK or anywhere else?" There is also specific questions regarding "voluntary departure".So I am totally confused... I should choose either ordered to leave or Residence Permit Extension had been refused but I can not choose which one I should choose.
According to UK Law, if your residence permit extension is refused,and you are given time to leave the country, and you left on your own expenses within the given time with the certificate which says you are ordered to leave, what does this implies?

Comment: Doesn't the answer to the question you asked last year in November also answer what you are asking here?

Comment: Your situation is: Obligation to leave (Ausreiseverplichtung) because the Residence Permit Extension had been refused. which you fulfilled within the required 9 days. If a remarks field is offered, you should write that. This is **not** considered an overstay in Germany. In UK legal terminology **voluntary departure** is sometimes used for someone who has overstayed, but leaves voluntary.

Comment: Related question [Difference between deportation and removal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/difference-between-deportation-and-removal) Does the UK application have two separate questions? Answer both with ‘Yes’ and explain why seems the solution.

Comment: Mark Johnson and Traveller, thanks a lot for your time and replies!

Comment: Tor-Einar Jarnbjo, thanks for your comment. l actually did not ask for the implication of my situation into the UK immigration law  in particular,last November. l was assuming my case would fall under the voluntary departure according to UK law, but after my New post,l have learnt that this terminology can lead to the assumption that l have overstayed in Germany(which is not the case) and l should evaulate other options when l answer for the question. Sorry if my post is repetitive.